# Multiple column closest date match pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge

I have two dataframes as such:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"col_a": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], "date_a": ["2019-01-03", "2019-02-04", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-15"]})
df_a.date_a = pd.to_datetime(df_a.date_a)
df_a.sort_values("date_a", inplace=True)
```

And

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "col_b": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b"],
    "date_b": [
        "2020-03-10",
        "2019-12-04",
        "2017-05-15",
        "2018-12-04",
        "2020-01-15",
        "2019-01-09",
        "2019-01-10",
        "2020-03-09",
    ],
})

df_b.date_b = pd.to_datetime(df_b.date_b)
df_b.sort_values("date_b", inplace=True)
```

I would like to merge df_b on df_a by the closest previous date conditional on the first column of each dataframe, with this as the result:

| Index | col_a | date_a | col_b | date_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2019-01-03 | a | 2017-05-15 |
| 1 | a | 2019-02-04 | a | 2019-01-09 |
| 2 | b | 2020-02-02 | b | 2020-01-15 |
| 3 | b | 2020-03-15 | b | 2020-03-09 |

Unfortunetely `pd.merge_asof` does not allow for multiple keys

Answer (score 4):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with defult `direction='backward'` parameter:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_a,
                   df_b, 
                   left_on='date_a', 
                   right_on='date_b', 
                   left_by='col_a', 
                   right_by='col_b')
print (df)
  col_a     date_a col_b     date_b
0     a 2019-01-03     a 2017-05-15
1     a 2019-02-04     a 2019-01-09
2     b 2020-02-02     b 2020-01-15
3     b 2020-03-15     b 2020-03-09
```